How to loop sending emails using GitHub Actions with variables values in the email body
I want to run Client-Credentials-Watchdog.yaml as cron job daily. It will fetch details of all the app credentials and find whose expiry date is less than 30 days to send out email notifications. Each and every app will have an unique owner ($lastModifiedBy from Get App by ID sample response) to whom the email should be send with variable values from Client-Credentials-Watchdog-script.groovy - Send emails until i < appListArraySize.
Current code only trigger one email to the hardcoded email address at the end of Client-Credentials-Watchdog.yaml
How can I make it dynamic and perform a loop?
Client-Credentials-Watchdog.yaml:
name: Client-Credentials-Watchdog
on:
    workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [abc]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: List files (Start)
        run: |
            ls
      - name: Install Groovy
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y groovy
      - name: Run Groovy script
        env:
          SECRET_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.USER }}
        run: groovy Client-Credentials-Watchdog-script.groovy
      - name: Send Email Notification
        uses: xyz/action-send-email@v4
        with:
          from-email: 'noreply-github@example.com'
          to-email: "user@example.com"
          subject: "Take Action: Renew credentials"
          email-format: 'html'
          body: "Renew ${{ attributes.value }} credentials that scheduled to expire on ${{ credentialsExpiresAtUnixTime }}."

Client-Credentials-Watchdog-script.groovy:
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

def host = "example.com"
def USER = System.getenv("SECRET_API_KEY")
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

// GET Apps
def getAppsListResponse = ["bash", "-c", "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request GET https://${host}/v1/organizations/org/apps"].execute().text
println "*** GET Apps List Response = $getAppsListResponse ***"

if (getAppsListResponse.contains('200')){
    println "*** Success ***"
    // Create an array
    def appsArray = getAppsListResponse.find(/\[.*\]/)
    getAppsListResponse = appsArray.replaceAll(/\[|\]/, '').split(',').collect { it.trim().replaceAll('"', '') }
    println "*** $getAppsListResponse ***"
    // Find array size
    println "*** App List Array size = $getAppsListResponse.size"
    def appListArraySize = getAppsListResponse.size
    
    for(int i=0; i< appListArraySize; i++){
        println "*** getAppsListResponse[${i}] = ${getAppsListResponse[i]}"
        // GET App by ID
        def getAppByIDResponse = ["bash", "-c", "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request GET https://${host}/v1/organizations/org/apps/${getAppsListResponse[i]}"].execute().text
        println "*** GET App by ID Response = $getAppByIDResponse ***"
        if(getAppByIDResponse.contains('200')){
            println "*** App found ***"
            // Find number of credential sets associated to an App
            def splitStatusCode = getAppByIDResponse.split('} 200')
            getAppByIDResponse = splitStatusCode[0] + '}'
            getAppByIDResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(getAppByIDResponse)
 
            def numberofCredentialsets = getAppByIDResponse.credentials.size()
            println "*** Number of Credential sets = $numberofCredentialsets"
            // 30 days in milliseconds
            def thirtyDaysUnixTime = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            // Current UNIX time (Milliseconds)
            def currentUnixTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()

            // Find each set expiry time
            for (int j=0; j< numberofCredentialsets; j++){
                def credential = getAppByIDResponse.credentials[j]
                def credentialsExpiresAtUnixTime = getAppByIDResponse.credentials[j].expiresAt
                println "credentials[${j}] expiresAt = $credentialsExpiresAtUnixTime"

                // Send email notification to App owner
                if((credentialsExpiresAtUnixTime - currentUnixTime) <= thirtyDaysUnixTime){
                    println "*** Send email notification with credentialsExpiresAtUnixTime variable***"
                }
                else{
                    println "*** Skip sending notification ***"
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            println "*** App not found ***"
            System.exit(1)
        }
    }
}
else{
    println "*** Failed ***"
    System.exit(1)
}

Get App by ID sample response:
{
  "accessType" : "",
  "apiProducts" : [ ],
  "appFamily" : "default",
  "appId" : "235258b",
  "attributes" : [ {
    "name" : "DisplayName",
    "value" : "Rohit-App"
  }, {
    "name" : "Notes",
    "value" : ""
  } ],
  "callbackUrl" : "",
  "createdAt" : 1717999606173,
  "createdBy" : "user@example.com",
  "credentials" : [ {
    "apiProducts" : [ {
      "apiproduct" : "Org-xyz",
      "status" : "approved"
    } ],
    "attributes" : [ ],
    "consumerKey" : "abc",
    "consumerSecret" : "456",
    "expiresAt" : 1749535606186,
    "issuedAt" : 1717999606186,
    "scopes" : [ ],
    "status" : "approved"
  }, {
    "apiProducts" : [ {
      "apiproduct" : "Org-xyz",
      "status" : "approved"
    } ],
    "attributes" : [ ],
    "consumerKey" : "def",
    "consumerSecret" : "456",
    "expiresAt" : 1749535606186,
    "issuedAt" : 1717999606186,
    "scopes" : [ ],
    "status" : "approved"
  }  ],
  "developerId" : "852",
  "lastModifiedAt" : 1717999606173,
  "lastModifiedBy" : "user@example.com",
  "name" : "Rahul-App",
  "scopes" : [ ],
  "status" : "approved"
}


The simpler solution seems to be directly send emails from your script. For GHA, you can create a matrix from your script and set up a new job with that. That should work but it'll spawn multiple job i.e. one job per generated config.

@Azeem, do you have any code references? I would like to use matrix, but how do I share groovy variables with my yaml?

See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/running-variations-of-jobs-in-a-workflow#example-using-an-output-to-define-two-matrices and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter.

I have used https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.12/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event and it works.
